# Sharding DAG in database

Tags: database, postgresql, sharding, directed-acyclic-graphs, horizontal-scaling

I have a many-to-many table with recursive relationships(child_id, parent_id) in the form of an acyclic directed graph, and I need to cascade unfold this graph from a particular graph node, which will be the root. How do I shard this table to avoid multiple network requests in case a certain child element is located on a different shard of the database from the parent? Sharding is necessary as the number of records in the relationship table can easily exceed the storage space of any drive.

I have absolutely no idea how it is possible to somehow optimize such a request

Comment: Please update the post with the table DDL, sample input data, and the expected output. Text descriptions alone are inadequate.

Comment: In the general case of course you can't. It's trivial to generate a graph that might cross a node boundary for any partitioning setup you pick. If your relationship table is genuinely in the hundreds of terabytes range and it doesn't have any rules you can rely on then at some point a single query will involve network traffic.